# JVM Profiling with IntelliJ

Tags: windows, intellij-idea

There's a documentation about JVM Profiling with IntelliJ IDE [here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2018/09/intellij-idea-2018-3-eap-git-submodules-jvm-profiler-macos-and-linux-and-more/). 
However when using Windows OS as the development environment the JVM profilers in the documentation does not work. Is there a way to use the native Windows `xperf` instead of async-profiler/honest profiler?

I am using IntelliJ 2019.3.1